# Mobile keyboard not selecting when opening input filed in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to select the text of my input field in unity, when clicking on it. It works in the editor, but none of selecting methods work on android devices.

Comment: You got an event system attached to your scene?

Comment: @Lotan Yes, I do.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard on android will only open itself by default on the following GUI elements: `GUI.TextField GUI.TextArea and GUI.PasswordField`. Make sure you are using one of these types for your inputfield. Also make sure "hide mobile input" is unchecked.

Alternatively you can make a call to open the onscreen keyboard yourself using `TouchScreenKeyboard.Open()`. Mind that if you open the touchscreen keyboard yourself it will not automatically populate the field field and you'll have to call to `TouchScreenKeyboard.text` to acces what the user is typing. Eg. `myInputfield.text = myTouchScreenKeyboard.text` to the set the text in `myInputField`

for all touchscreenkeyboard functionality see the docs [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileKeyboard.html) and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard.html)

Comment: The keyboard open correctly, the problem is with selecting it's text on opening.

Comment: Sorry i misread! have you tried checking what `TouchScreenBoard.canGetSelection` is set to? this may be false, and if it is you can enable it by calling `TouchScreenKeyboard.selection` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard-selection.html

Comment: okay, thank you. TouchScreenBoard.canGetSelection is false, but TouchScreenKeyboard.selection does not work either.

Comment: Only thing i can think of then is that maybe `Interactable` and/or `Raycast target` are ticked off on the Text/Input field components. are those both enabled? and maybe try turning off `rich text` on the text component, since Rich text input is not supported

Comment: Ok, thank you. I tried turning off rich text, it does not help.